# Объекты JS свойства обьекта

Tags: javascript

```
function name ({item}){
  {name,surname,phone} = item; // Ошибка если в item нет свойства name и других свойств

}

//or

function name({item}){
  const people = {name:item.name || "", surname:item.surname || "", phone: item.phone || ""} // Ошибка если в item нет свойства name   и других свойств
}
```

Если есть возможность в малом количестве кода применить условие: если нет обьекта item в аргументах (аргумент должен быть обязательно в фигурных скобках) то в свойства name, surname, phone была пустая строка или undefined. Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Сделайте дефолтный объект с пустыми полями и в любой непонятно ситуации передавайте в функции именно его как аргумент. Это будет а-ля реализация паттерна Null Object

Comment: `let {name, surname, phone} = {};` — выполнил, получилось 3 undefined переменных, ошибки не наблюдается. У вас изначально в item точно объект?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME нет, в функцию может прийти либо undefined либо обьект

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Создай ответ. Поставлю галочку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлагаю вам рассмотреть паттерн **[Null Object](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))** , **[пример2](https://refactoring.guru/ru/introduce-null-object)**, **[пример js](https://functionalprogramming.medium.com/from-null-object-design-pattern-to-maybe-functor-in-javascript-a398f947e3df#:%7E:text=The%20Null%20Object%20Design%20pattern&text=The%20null%20object%20pattern%20is,they%20don%27t%20do%20nothing.)**

По сути это будет объект, где у свойств будут заданы значения по умолчанию, приемлемые для вас, в случае если нужного конкретного объекта не существует (в вашем случае у всех свойств пустые значения) и передавать его как аргумент функции, когда это необходимо

Comment: Патер Null Object больше подходит к случаям авторизаций пользователя, то что мне нужно, пасибо)

Comment: @Locker  данный паттерн даже имеет намного шире спектр применения нежели единовременная авторизация)

Answer (score 2):

Вам, случайно, не это нужно? Тут предохранитель на случай обоих `undefined`: и на случай отсутствия аргумента, и на случай отсутствия в нём свойства `item`:

```js
function name({ item = {} } = {}) {
  const { name, surname, phone } = item;

  console.log(name, surname, phone);
}

name();
```